# Why there is difference in accuracy when calculating manually using confusion matrix and while using precision_score from scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

This is the code which I am running

```
import pandas as pd
whole_population = pd.read_csv('Whole_population_with_Class_column.csv')
whole_population = whole_population.drop(whole_population.columns[0],axis=1)
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score, accuracy_score, roc_auc_score, matthews_corrcoef

actual = whole_population['Landslide']
predicted = whole_population['Jenks_Class']
confusion_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(actual, predicted)

accuracy = accuracy_score(actual, predicted)
precision = precision_score(actual, predicted)
recall = recall_score(actual, predicted)
f1_score = f1_score(actual, predicted)
mcc = matthews_corrcoef(actual, predicted)

print(accuracy)
print(precision)
print(recall)
print(f1_score)
print(mcc)
```

It is generating the confusion matrix
[Confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxm4y.png)

The output produced is

0.6647094256133509   *(accuracy)*

0.9985021160091312   *(precision)*

0.664066520207418    *(recall)*

0.7976474608673689   *(f1 score)*

0.06769568834135027  *(mcc)*

I know that scikit learn generates confusion matrix in the following form:

TN | FP

FN | TP

and for the same if I apply the precision formula:
precision = TP/(TP+FN) = 4720/(4720+407361) = 0.0114540588 (using values from matrix)

Why I am getting the different precision values while calculating it using confusion matrix manually and while directly using precision_score?

Similar case seen for recall as well.